# How can services be shared between Stacks in different AWS Accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have the following structure of my AWS Organization

```
Root // account
├─ Infrastructure // OU
│  ├─ Shared Services Account
├─ Workloads // OU
│  ├─ Dev // OU
│  │  ├─ Developer A's Development Account
│  │  ├─ Developer B's Development Account
│  │  ├─ Developer C's Development Account
│  │  ├─ Integration Account
│  ├─ Staging // OU
│  │  ├─ Staging Account
│  ├─ Prod // OU
│  │  ├─ Production Account
```

With this organization I want to achieve the following requirements:

1. **Shared Services Account:**

   1. Store the monorepo source code in AWS CodeCommit.
   2. Store Slack notifications configuration in AWS ChatBot.
2. **Individual Developer Accounts:**

   1. Each developer should have a separate AWS Account.
   2. Developers are to work using the Cloud9 environment.
3. **Integration Environment (QA):**

   1. Utilized for testing features after merging.
4. **Staging Environment:**

   1. Designed to replicate the production environment for final tests.
5. **Production Environment:**

   1. Dedicated to hosting production resources..

The 1.1. and 2.1 points I want to achieve by using the AWS CDK. This is my initial AWS CDK code:

```js
export class SharedRecourcesStack extends Stack {
  readonly repository: aws_codecommit.Repository;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const sourceCodeAsset = new aws_s3_assets.Asset(this, "SourceCodeAsset", {
      path: join(__dirname, "../../"),
      exclude: ["node_modules", "cdk.out", ".git"],
    });

    this.repository = new aws_codecommit.Repository(this, "ProjectRepository", {
      repositoryName: "ProjectRepository",
      description: "The monorepo for all Project source code",
      code: aws_codecommit.Code.fromAsset(sourceCodeAsset),
    });
  }
}
```

```js
interface DeveloperEnvironmentStackProps extends StackProps {
  readonly repository: aws_codecommit.Repository;
}

export class DeveloperEnvironmentStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: DeveloperEnvironmentStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const defaultVpc = aws_ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "DefaultVPC", {
      isDefault: true,
    });

    const cloud9 = new aws_cloud9_alpha.Ec2Environment(this, "Cloud9", {
      imageId: aws_cloud9_alpha.ImageId.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
      vpc: defaultVpc,
      clonedRepositories: [
        aws_cloud9_alpha.CloneRepository.fromCodeCommit(props.repository, "./"),
      ],
      automaticStop: Duration.minutes(30),
      description: "The Cloud9 environment for Project",
      connectionType: aws_cloud9_alpha.ConnectionType.CONNECT_SSM,
      instanceType: new aws_ec2.InstanceType("t2.micro"),
      // owner: aws_cloud9_alpha.Owner.
    });
  }
}
```

```js
const app = new cdk.App();

const sharedResources = new SharedRecourcesStack(app, "SharedRecourcesStack", {
  env: {
    account: "11111111", // Shared Services Account
    region: "eu-central-1",
  },
});

new DeveloperEnvironmentStack(app, "Cloud9Stack", {
  env: {
    account: "22222222", // Developer A's Account
    region: "eu-central-1",
  },
  repository: sharedResources.repository,
});

app.synth()
```

But whenever I try to deploy resources it says

```
Error: Stack "DeveloperEnvironmentStack" cannot reference {SharedRecourcesStack/ProjectRepository/Resource[CloneUrlHttp]} in stack "SharedRecourcesStack". Cross stack references are only supported for stacks deployed to the same account or between nested stacks and their parent stack
```

I understand that sharing resources (such as a repository) between different accounts is not allowed, but I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.

Intuitively, placing the Cloud9 configuration in the Shared Services Account seems incorrect because I prefer to keep developer resources in their own AWS accounts. It would be ideal if they could pull the repository from the Shared Services Account and use it. Additionally, whenever they push changes, they should push them to the Shared Services Account.

Could you assist me in solving this problem? Alternatively, could you share your thoughts on whether my AWS Organization is poorly organized, which might be the cause of this issue?